# EmberJS: How to render a template on select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm new to ember and am trying to figure out how to render a template when a select control changes.

CODE:

```
    App.LocationTypeController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    selectedLocationType: null,

    locationTypeChanged: function() {
        //Render template
    }.observes('selectedLocationType')
});

{{view Ember.Select 
  contentBinding="model"
  selectionBinding="selectedLocationType"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
```

When the locationType changes the locationTypeChanged function is fired in the controller.
But how do I render some content into the dom from there? (this.render()?)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you have to use `this.render()` only, but the key here is `into` option inside it.

```
App.LocationTypeController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

 selectedLocationType: null,

 locationTypeChanged: function() {
    var selectedLocationType = this.get('selectedLocationType');
    this.send('changeTemplate',selectedLocationType);
 }.observes('selectedLocationType')
});
```

Have the action in your route as

```
changeTemplate: function(selection) {
          this.render('template'+selection.id,{into:'locationType'});
 }
```

and have an `{{outlet}}` in your `locationType`'s template.

```
{{view Ember.Select 
       contentBinding="model"
       selectionBinding="selectedLocationType"
       optionValuePath="content.id"
       optionLabelPath="content.name"}} 

{{outlet}}
```

Sample [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ekaGipO/14/edit) for your requirement

Answer (score 4):

If you need to show only a frament, when exist something selected, you can use the `if` handlebars helper:

In your template

```
...

{{#if selectedLocationType}}
  Any content here will be visible when selectedLocationType has some value
{{/if}}

...

{{view Ember.Select 
  contentBinding="model"
  selectionBinding="selectedLocationType"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
```

I hope it helps